# Question on showing a space as a non-hausdorff manifold .

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Let $I=[0,1]$ & define $t\sim s$ iff $t+s=1$ when $0\leq t \leq \frac{1}{4}.$ Show $X=\frac{I}{\sim}$ is a non-hausdorff manifold .

$\mathbf {My \  approach}:$ Here, I can't see for which $2$ points, the hausdorffness is failed .
For points $[p]$  when $0< p <\frac{1}{2}$, a local open set homeomorphic to an Euclidean interval is immediate as no identification is going on there .

And for the rest, an image is attached .[image]

A small hint is very much required, thanks in advance .

Comment: look up "line with two origins"

Comment: Yes, it's a manifold but there wasn't the "two origins" can never be separated by any disjoint open sets .But, I can't see any connection with that in here .

Comment: Are you sure that $\ 0\le t\le\frac{1}{4}\ $ rather than $\ 0\le t<\frac{1}{4}\ $ is the second condition defining the equivalence $\ \sim\ $? If it were the latter, then you would have $\ \left[\frac{1}{4}\right]\ne\left[\frac{3}{4}\right]\ $, and those two points couldn't be separated by two disjoint open sets.

Comment: I think you are right , the assignment sheet has a mistake then .

Comment: There is another mistake in the assignment, the interval $I$ should be **open**, not closed: Using closed interval creates a nonempty boundary of your non-Hausdorff manifold even if you use the inequality $0\le t<1/4$ for your equivalence relation.